# Edit results inline

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am returning my views in the style *draggableviews*. At the bottom you have a save order. This obviously must set the CCK field I have for weight. Would it be possible to update over columns as well? Ideally you would be able to edit the columns returned either by free text or drop downs.

By the sounds of it I think I may need to code something myself.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you will need to code something. Luckily, the [DraggableViews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module is there as an example.

You might also want to look into [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), the 10,000 pound Gorilla in the World of My-Views-Change-Things.

If you want the draggableviews drag-action to directly set multiple fields, it sounds like you need to visit it's issue queue, post a request, and be prepared to offer a patch. It sounds to me like what you need is a hook in draggableviews that allows you to specify additional field and a callback function for how to update it in the course of dragging.